# PhpStorm GitHub doesn't push some files and classes

Tags: github, phpstorm, yii2-advanced-app, git-push

I have created a Yii-Advanced project in PhpStorm and pushed the project to GitHub via PhpStorm's VCS option. However, some of the files are not pushed to the my repository. I have tried to push again but it didn't work. How can I push those files?

Edit: File names are green colour.

Comment: Do you see any errors? You can take a look in the logs (Help | Show logs in <...>) to find a bit more information.

Comment: "Everything is up-to-date" This is what in the logs.

Comment: Green highlighting usually means that the files are added to the staging area but not committed yet. Have you tried committing them first with Git | Commit?

Comment: I tried using "git commit " and " git push" in terminal but it said "There are no changes."

Comment: First do git add thatFileName and then try git commit. It will commit the newly added files. I suppose that Those mentioned files might not be tracked in git.

Comment: PhpStorm can "lose" the path to your git executable. Go to Preferences > Version Control > Git and at the top of the window you will see "Path to Git Executable". The path will be in the input field, next to that will be a "Test" button. Click that to test if PhpStorm can still find git. If that does not work, circumvent PhpStorm and check your repository status via the CLI. You should learn git using CLI for circumstances like these, it always works no matter the platform. For example: `git status` to check the status of your repo.